# Plants vs Zombies on an iBook G4 - can I fix the gameplay being much faster than normal?

Tags: macos, plants-vs-zombies

I'm playing Plants vs Zombies on an iBook G4 - can I fix the gameplay being much faster than normal? I don’t see anything about it in the options menu, and there doesn’t seem to be anything else I can do. Is this how the game is supposed to play on Mac or am I missing something? The game audio is just fine, and I don’t notice anything else being wrong.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why you think the game is running faster than it should be?  Have you done any research or compared notes with online playthroughs, for example?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as fixing it to a faster gameplay. There is only one speed in the gameplay, which is fixed. However, if you're not using a Mac (which is the case unfortunately), then you can go here
http://www.techspot.com/downloads/3131-game-speed-adjuster.html      to download a gamespeed adjuster to increase your gameplay speed.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this issue as well. The game runs at 200% speed on my iBook G4 1ghz model. I am assuming the speed at which the game is running at is tied to the framerate/clocks of the cpu, which is odd cause most releases after the G3 era should've already gotten this simple thing right. But it doesn't seem like that's the case however.

My suggestion would to be just play it at that insane speed and put down as many peashooters and sprites to artificially lag the game down to an acceptable speed (which is absurd but I have done it ), run it on the recommended specs which is a slower G4 chip. Or just play it on a device where it is properly optimised like a modern smartphone or computer. Cause this PPC port is just not great.